# Popper não encontrado ao utilizar o vuejs no Laravel

Tags: vue.js

Em um de meus projetos Laravel (5.8) estou utilizando o VueJS, basicamente só criei alguns componentes, não realizei nenhuma alteração na configuração default do vue.

Mas estou recebendo o erro:

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` para popper.js.map

Não entendi já que no arquivo Bootstrap.js do vue tem o trecho:

```
try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}
```

Comment: Tenta instalar a dependência: https://www.npmjs.com/package/popper

Comment: mas ele está instalado ("popper.js": "^1.12",). Faz parte do package.json (default) do Laravel.